# Twice differentiable function vanishing at 0.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $$f\left(\frac1n\right)=0\text{ for every positive }n.$$ Prove that $$f(0)=f’(0)=f”(0)=0.$$ 
$f(0)=0$ follows easily from continuity at $0$. $f’(0)=0$ follows from the sequential limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ applied to $\left\{\frac1n\right\}$. But I am unable to prove $f”(0)=0$. I need help please.

Comment: Do you mean that $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) = 0$ for every positive **integer** $n$? If it is true for every positive real $n$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Positive integer n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the MVT on each interval $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ to see $f'(x_n)= 0$ along a sequence $x_n\to 0^+.$ Now use

$$f''(0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f'(x_n)-f'(0)}{x_n}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: +1. This continues for any order derivative at $0$ as long as we are guaranteed it's existence.

Comment: Thank you for the nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f''(0)>0$;

Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f'(x)/x=f''(0)>0$.

Since $f'(x)/x$ is continuos there is a $\delta >0$ s.t.

$f'(x)/x >0$ for $x \in (0,\delta)$ i .e.

$f'(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,\delta)$.

$f$ is strictly increasing.

Choose $1/n <\delta$ , then

$f(1/n)>0$, a contradiction.

Similar argument for $f''(0)<0.$

Comment: Thank you for a different way of solving this problem.

Comment: +1 and there is no need to say that $f'(x) /x $ is continuous. Just say that it has a positive limit and therefore it must be positive itself in some  neighborhood.

Comment: Paramand.Yes.Thank you.